# Bootstrap: row of size three on the left and on the right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have something like the following

```
<div class=content-fluid>
    <div class=page-header>
        <div class=row>
            <div class="pull-left col-md-3">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'd like is that the right column always maintains its size, rather than going into "small-mode" where each column becomes a full-width row, and that when the window is too small, the right column slides underneath the left column. This is turning out to be pretty complicated to achieve!

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `content-fluid`, unless defined by you, should be `container-fluid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to implement's bootstrap `col-sm-3` and `col-xs-3` classes in addition to your `col-md-3` class. You can view their grid documentation on the official bootstrap website.

So therefore... `<div class="col-xs-3">`

You can also utilize them to be at different widths depending on viewport size, per example:  `<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">`

Comment: each size applies for all sizes bigger. to make the markup simpler you could use `<div class="col-xs-3">`

Answer (score 1):

should be you sue bootstrap grid this way

```
<div class=content-fluid>
        <div class=page-header>
            <div class=row>
                <div class="pull-left col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

use col-3 for all the "size" of the  bootstrap grid and 12 for the small size on left